# azure sdk deleteAsync request content null

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I have an azure mobile service with a .NET backend and am unable to delete a record. When I debug into the Delete function, the item is null. When I call this.Request in the immediate window, I get the string returned at the bottom. I used to use a node js backend, but have switched to a .NET backend, so the client side code hasn't changed.

Review Item class:

```
public class ReviewItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public string Line4 { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

Client side:

```
var dbReviewItems = await reviewTable.ToListAsync();
foreach (var item in dbReviewItems)
    await reviewTable.DeleteAsync(item);
```

Server Side:

```
public void Delete(T item)
{
    Context.Delete(item.Id);
    Context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Context:

```
// passing in Id because passing the item caused a not found exception
public T Delete(string Id) 
{
    var item = Find(Id);
    if (item == null) return null;
    return Context.Set<T>().Remove(item);
}
```

Controller's Request (running on azure server in debug mode, called from the wp emulator):

```
{Method: DELETE, RequestUri: 'https://xxxx.azure-mobile.net/tables/ReviewItem/016f5328-c6fa-4b14-9c41-73976a0afda8', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:  
{  
  Cache-Control: no-cache  
  Connection: Keep-Alive  
  Accept: application/json  
  Accept-Encoding: gzip  
  Host: xxxx.azure-mobile.net  
  Max-Forwards: 10  
  User-Agent: ZUMO/1.3  
  User-Agent: (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.10.0.12358; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.21121.0)  
  X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT  
  X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: xxxx  
  X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: xxxx  
  X-ZUMO-AUTH: xxxx  
  X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.10.0.12358; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.21121.0)  
  X-LiveUpgrade: 1  
  X-ARR-LOG-ID: xxxx  
  DISGUISED-HOST: xxxx.azure-mobile.net  
  X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: xxxx  
  X-Original-URL: /tables/ReviewItem/016f5328-c6fa-4b14-9c41-73976a0afda8  
  X-Forwarded-For: 70.186.182.236:4945  
  X-ARR-SSL: 2048|128|DC=com, DC=microsoft, DC=corp, DC=redmond, CN=MSIT Machine Auth CA 2|C=US, S=WA, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft, OU=OrganizationName, CN=*.azurewebsites.net  
  Content-Length: 0  
}}  
    Content: {System.Net.Http.StreamContent}  
    Headers: {Cache-Control: no-cache  
Connection: Keep-Alive  
Accept: application/json  
Accept-Encoding: gzip  
Host: xxxx.azure-mobile.net  
Max-Forwards: 10  
User-Agent: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.10.0.12358; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.21121.0)  
X-ZUMO-FEATURES: TT  
X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: xxxx  
X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: xxxx  
X-ZUMO-AUTH: xxxx  
X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/1.3 (lang=Managed; os=Windows Phone; os_version=8.10.0.12358; arch=Win32NT; version=1.3.21121.0)  
X-LiveUpgrade: 1  
X-ARR-LOG-ID: a252fe87-03c9-487a-87c8-aa454c906f79  
DISGUISED-HOST: xxxx.azure-mobile.net  
X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: xxxx  
X-Original-URL: /tables/ReviewItem/016f5328-c6fa-4b14-9c41-73976a0afda8  
X-Forwarded-For: 70.186.182.236:4945  
X-ARR-SSL: 2048|128|DC=com, DC=microsoft, DC=corp, DC=redmond, CN=MSIT Machine Auth CA 2|C=US, S=WA, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft, OU=OrganizationName, CN=*.azurewebsites.net  
}  
    Method: {DELETE}  
    Properties: Count = 11  
    RequestUri: {https://xxxx.azure-mobile.net/tables/ReviewItem/016f5328-c6fa-4b14-9c41-73976a0afda8}  
    Version: {1.1}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a dumb dumb. I made the controller's delete method receive an object. It's supposed to receive a string Id.